# Mirth Connect send old messages when changing server

Tags: mirth

I have a Mirth application installed in Ubuntu server. I try to move the application from one server to another server (DRC server). When I moved the application, somehow the Mirth keep sending old messages to the channel.

The source of sending channel is using Database Reader and connecter type for destinations is using TCP Sender. Im using Mirth Connect version 3.5.2

Does anyone know why this is happening. Is there any log files that I need to clear when moving the application from one server to another?

Comment: Are you flagging your database rows as sent after you send the messages?

Comment: we use temporary table only, one the data inserted in the table, the table then is cleared.

Comment: How are you making sure that you aren't pulling the same data into your temporary table with each query?  Do you pull by a certain date range, flags, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for several reasons. Application logic, queued messages. My guess is you moved appdata directory along with installation, if so you must be seeing similar stats from where you moved.

Mirth stores all channels information, transactions etc. by *default* under `appdata` folder. If you are using default settings it'll use `derby` db. You can connect to that DB with any DB client support JDBC. i.e.
[SQuirelL](https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/SQuirreL_Derby.html) or DB [Visualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/) and that can give you an idea what's happening.

I recommend you to make a clear setup. Then, you can export/import your channels into your new environment. You can also consider using any other DB, oracle/sqlserver/mysql.. for Mirth. Current version is 3.9.10 and it has better support for DBs other than derby.

As mentioned in the comments your application logic also matters.